# VS 2015 build error: PE image does not contain metadata

Tags: c#, visual-studio

While building a c# class library (.NET 4.0) using VS 2015 I am getting the error: PE image does not contain metadata.

I tried the obvious stuff which doesn't help:
1. perform clean entire solution
2. REstart Visual Studio and rebuild all

strange thing is that the even though the DLL builds and works, this annoying error is still staying in the error window of the build output.

The complete error reads:
Error while reading c:/XX/xxx/DEBUG/mylib.dll :  PE image doesn't contain metadata.

Any ideas?

EDIT:  after  I restarted my computer the error went away.  This is not really a solution, so I did not answer my own question, but at least it works around an annoying error.